# backward series in python where every next term is (prev1*prev2+prev3)

Tags: python-3.x

Please help to write pytnon code. The series goes like ....previous3, previous2, previous1  Nth terms. And every next term is (previous1*previous2+previous3).
I have tried this

```
n = int(input('Give the number of terms of the series'))
prev1 = 1
prev2 = 1
prev3 = 2
for i in range(n):
    next = prev1*prev2+prev3
    prev3 = next
    prev2 = prev3
    prev1 = prev2
print('The series is ', next)
```

Comment: What happened next ?

Comment: Well the output was not a series, it only gave me the value of next variable.

Comment: Indent the `print`

Comment: You haven't described the problem you're having. What do you expect? What are you getting?

Comment: @gogaz         I did a bit change in the for loop, for i in range(n):
        prev4 = prev1*prev2 + prev3
        prev1 = prev2
        prev2 = prev3
        prev3 = prev4
    print(prev4, end=',')  the output is  3,5,11,26,81,367,2473  when n=7 and last print() is indented. But i expect the output to be like "..., 2473,367,81,26,11,5,3,2,1,1"

Comment: @shanmu ganathan  yes, thanks. after i corrected the typo, the result is the same, i.e. 3,5,11,26,81,367... But want the output to be 2473,367,81,26,11,5,3,2,1,1

Answer (score 0):

Dude, you missed a parenthesis at the end of the first line!